# Como evitar a redução na largura das colunas?

Tags: c#, vb.net, itextsharp

Estou utilizando a biblioteca itextsharp para geração de relatórios em PDF e apesar de conseguir gerar documentos com layout agradavel e atribuir larguras especificas através de um array de dimensões :

```
Tabela.SetWidths(VetorDeLarguras)
```

Entretanto, quando o número de colunas da minha tabela é muito grande, então a biblioteca acaba reduzindo a largura das colunas para que outras colunas possam ocupar espaço na tabela. Existe algum meio de impedir essa redução automatica na largura das colunas? mesmo que a tabela extrapole a página.

Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe `PdfPtable.SetTotalWidth(float[] columnWidth)` que fixa a largura das colunas em valores absolutos.

Para escrever apenas as colunas que se pretendem por página temos `PdfPTable.WriteSelectedRows()`.